# When should the valid visual cue be shown to the user on a pre-filled form field?

Tags: forms, validation

It makes sense to show a valid visual cue (eg: green border, green check, etc) when a user is filling a form field and the data is considered valid.

[image]

What if the user opened the form with pre-filled data? For example, when editing something.

When would be the appropriate moment to show the valid visual cue on form fields that were not edited by the user?

When the form is loaded?

On focus and blur events?

When the form is submitted?

Never?

Answer (score 1):

No right answer here, depends on strength of cue and use case. Blur events and submit events may go very wrong if the page reloads in form submit, like it does on some tech stacks, causing user to never see the cue. Can you do it on every keystroke?

Comment: The question is about pre-filled form inputs that are not altered by the user so it can't be done on change/input events.